# Save Richtextbox text in TabControl to a file

Tags: c#

I have a code that will write me all the text from all RichTextBoxes that are in the TabPage. The problem is that it does not save any text.

```
string projectFile = projectPathFolder + @"\" + projectName + @"\" + projectName + ".project";

for (int i = 0; i < tabControl1.RowCount; i++)
{
    RichTextBox richText = tabControl1.Controls[i] as RichTextBox;

    using (var stream = new StreamWriter(File.Create(projectFile)))
    {
        stream.Write(scintilla.Text);
    }

    File.WriteAllText(projectFile, "// " + tabControl1.TabPages[i].Text + "\n\n" + richText.Text, Encoding.UTF8);
}
```

Comment: Consider using [`Path.Combine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx) to build up your paths.

Comment: I don't think your question is particularly clear as you aren't really stating what you're trying to do, bar what can be gleaned from the code snippet.. Perhaps you could edit your question to include some more details, e.g. how the contents of the `TabControl` are setup and what you are expecting the code to do, e.g. save the contents of all tabs, the current tab, etc.

Comment: Do you have multiple RichTextBox controls in one Tab?...or  multiple Tabs, each with one or more RichTextBoxes in them?  Where is the `scintilla` variable coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RowCount` is the wrong property to use as it returns the number of rows, not tabs. E.g. you could have 6 tabs but `RowCount` may still only be 1 if the tabs are narrow and the control wide.

Firstly, are you trying to enumerate *all* pages in the `TabControl`? If that's the case, use `TabCount` in your `for` loop, **not** `RowCount`

```
for (int i = 0; i < tabControl1.TabCount; i++)
```

If you only want to use the current tab, then get rid of the loop and just use `tabControl1.SelectedTab`.

Secondly, the line trying to get the `RichTextBox` is never going to work. A `TabControl` can only host `TabPage` instances, and trying to access `RichTextBox` instances via the `Controls` property is simply not going to work.  You will need to get the `TabPage` first and then either enumerate the controls on it to find the `RichTextBox`, or if there is only a single control per page then you could directly access it.

```
RichTextBox richText = tabControl1.TabPages[i].Controls[0] as RichTextBox;
```

I'm not at all sure why you have that `using` block to write content to `projectFile` - it's just going to get overwritten by the call to `File.WriteAllText`.

As an aside, joining paths by hand is bad practice - try using `Path.Combine`, e.g. `Path.Combine(projectPathFolder, projectName, projectName + ".project");`

Edit: One other point. You're using `as RichTextBox`, which generally means you accept the cast may not be valid and return `null`. However, you're not doing an explicit `null` check on that result. If you expect failure, then wrap the  `File.WriteAllText` statement in a null check. If you don't expect failure, then make the cast explicit and let it crash at the point of the cast - better to fail early than later.

```
RichTextBox richText = (RichTextBox)tabControl1.TabPages[i].Controls[0];
```

Hope this helps.